# Am I calculating LogAUC / pAUC correctly?

Tags: model-evaluations, model-selection, metric

Hope you are well.

I was wondering how one would calculate logAUC? I have an implementation but I don't think it's correct.

I'm trying to recreate the metric in [this](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41596-021-00597-z) manuscript. See figure 2.

Any help would be great appreciated.

```
lower_bound, upper_bound = np.log10(0.001), np.log10(1)
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(ground_truth, predictions, pos_label=1)
log_fpr = np.log10(fpr)

tpr = np.append(tpr, np.interp([lower_bound, upper_bound], log_fpr, tpr))
log_fpr = np.append(log_fpr, [lower_bound, upper_bound])

x = np.sort(log_fpr)
y = np.sort(tpr)

lower_bound_idx = np.where(x == lower_bound)[-1][-1]
upper_bound_idx = np.where(x == upper_bound)[-1][-1]

trim_x = x[lower_bound_idx:upper_bound_idx + 1]
trim_y = y[lower_bound_idx:upper_bound_idx + 1]

logAUC = np.round(auc(trim_x, trim_y) / 2,2)
```

Comment: Have you looked at the definition on [the following page](https://wiki.docking.org/index.php/LogAUC), which seems to be related to the software mentioned in the paper? In addition, I found [the following commit](https://github.com/mims-harvard/TDC/pull/140/files#diff-90a25278ce93bda5c965ce474b21240c1d9f312c4b7db33e226fbe5648c55161R52) on github which contains an explanation, which you may have based your code on given that it is almost identical to yours.

Comment: Thanks Oxbowerce. I actually pulled the code from that post but just wanted to confirm if this was indeed correct. Thank you